# Create custom login and provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-profile

I'm developing a site that needs to store additional user information other than the default in the CreateUserWizard in ASP.Net4.0.  It's been a few years since I developed (and mainly used windows forms) and this is my first acutal site using ASP and webforms.  I need to store the following fields:

```
FirstName
LastName
Company
PartsList
Address (which will include city, state, zip)
Phone
Email
Username
Password
Role (which role they belong to)
Password Question
Password Answer
Comments
```

I have done some research but haven't really found a good way to store all these fields and how to validate them during login if they are a custom provider.  I guess I'm looking for a tutorial on how to setup a custom provider where I can store all of this information, whether it is in a SQL table or a dictionary of some kind.  Also, users should be able to edit their own information and administrators of the website should have the ability to remove/suspend user accounts.  Does anyone know of any good examples on how I would do this?  I would imagine I would need to create a class to store all the info for each user, but then what?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is use `FormsAuthentication` with a custom `RoleProvider`. I find it a huge advantage to use some built-in methods to handle authentication. You can then use any means to store your data for later access. However, in your question it seems a database would be perferable, since web is stateless.

I'd have the data handy in the `Session` object once the user is authenticated and then update the database as necessary (edits, deletes, ect.).

Look here: http://techbrij.com/206/custom-role-provider-based-sitemap-navigation-in-asp-net

Here's a little more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending how much work that you want to do, you can probably get things built by using the default Profile Provider and use the Profile to store the additional information. From a storage perspective, the out of the box solution using the SQL Profile Provider is not that pretty- it basically stores the information in one field. However, it will allow you to get up and running in a short period of time, and then you can replace it later down the line.